# return value from promise Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm working with Sequelize, but I'm having trouble to get my requisition's return.

This is what I got so far:

```
var m = Messagem.findAll({}).then((mensagens)=>{
console.log(mensagens); //  i have a reponse :D
return mensagens;
});

console.log(m);

Promise {
_bitField: 2097152,
_fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
_rejectionHandler0: undefined,
_promise0: undefined,
_receiver0: undefined,
_boundTo: Messagem }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return a value from the promise resolution handler
(well, you can, but it will be the result of the resolution or rejection of the promise that is returned by the `.then()` method itself, like in this example).

In your case `m` is a promise so you need to use it as such. Instead of:

```
console.log(m);
```

you have to do:

```
m.then(console.log);
```

or this:

```
console.log(await m);
```

if you are inside a function declared with the `async` keyword.

See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805) for more info about that. See also [**other answers about promises**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A613198+promise).